# In Pandemic can I immediately cure disease to return to the 7 card limit?

Tags: pandemic

I have 7 cards in my hand 4 red, 3 yellow (both uncured diseases). I take a red card from another player in my city, can I immediately cure disease (there is a research center in my city) to enable me to return below the 7 card limit?

Answer (score 7):

You can't do this, since you discard immediately if at any time you have more than 7 cards. From [the rules](http://zmangames.com/rulebooks/Pandemic.pdf):

> If you ever have more than 7 cards in hand (after first resolving any Epidemic cards you may have drawn), discard cards or play Event cards until you have 7 cards in hand (...).

Drawing epidemics is the only exception; those don't stay in your hand long enough to cause you to discard.

This is also mentioned under "commonly overlooked rules":

> Your hand limit applies immediately after getting a card from another player.

Note that the reminder text in the corner of the board might lead you astray here, saying:

> 1. Take 4 actions
> 2. Draw 2 cards
>
>    - Resolve epidemics
>    - Discard to 7 cards
> 3. Draw Infection cards

You should read that as a reminder that you may need to discard then, not as an indication that you *don't* need to discard at other times.

Answer (score 2):

No, the action of discarding a card for having more than 7 cards is an atomic action that occurs before you can take your next turn action.

Comment: Discarding a card is *not* an action, and it's *certainly not* atomic.

Comment: @TheChaz2.0 I think Joe meant action in a generic sense, as opposed to your four actions per turn (which he referred to as turn actions). For the atomic part, the only way I know of that anything can happen during discarding other than the discard itself is playing event cards to get down to 7 instead of discarding - is that what you meant? It's not terribly clear from your comment.

Comment: @TheChaz2.0 That is what I was trying to say with my comment, that the player had to deal with discarding a card before the turn could continue and they could cure a disease.

Comment: It should be **automatic**, not *atomic*.

Comment: I wrote atomic action because it is describing the discard as happening at the same time as getting the 8th card and there is not time between drawing and discarding to do another action.